# How to solve org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, lombok

Mybatis throws below exception when using a foreign key to map one table to another (one = @One).
Entity class has lombok @Getter @Setter and @Builder.

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com....XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity class with a Builder needs both  NoArgsConstructor and AllArgsConstructor for it to work. Otherwise it throws org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class without any clear root cause.

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```